# Is there access conflict between users when they create/remove a global temp table in sql?

Tags: sql, locking, global-variables, simultaneous, database-concurrency

I have a SQL stored proc which is supposed to be executed by multiple users. Every user will execute this proc on the same server and same database. During the execution, it will create global temp tables and drop them at the end (for example, `##temp_1`, `##temp_2`, etc.). When the proc creates the global temp tables, it uses the following code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..##temp_1') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##temp_1
```

So my question is, when `User A` created `##temp_1` and `##temp_2`, `User B` starts on another machine and start to create his `##temp_1`. According to the above code, `##temp_1` will be removed from the database if exists. Will this operation affects `User A`? If the users are affecting each other, is there a way to avoid it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify that users data is unique to that user and the other users entry the same that way it will store both